# See the java heap content in run time

Tags: java, memory, jvm

I am looking for any tool that allows me to see how objects are created on heap in run time. 
I was using VisualVM - Profiles but was not able to find when a variable of specific type (the one I am looking for) is being created. Maybe I do something wrong...
I will be also thankful getting any hint how to get such information using any API.

Regards,
Marcin

Answer (score 4):

Typically, profilers (such as [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html)) will allow you to see this - see for example the [Allocation recording explained](http://blog.ej-technologies.com/2009/08/allocation-recording-explained.html) screencast.

However, they achieve this by attaching an agent to the JVM that allows them to intercept the low-level operations - this information is not usually available to either users or Java programs.  As such, you won't be able to see the heap via JMX apps such as JConsole or JVisualVM.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will try it ant let you know.

Comment: VisualVM has nice feature which is heapdump - that reflect heap content and can be very useful. BTW - how to connect any running app from JProfiler?

Answer (score 2):

Inside VisualVM Profiler, select the Settings and specify the class you want to profile. May be you also need to look on the option which record allocation stacks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to debug a program and that using the debugger would be the best option.  You should be able to add a conditional breakpoint to stop the program when a variable is assigned the value you are looking for.  This will allow you to see all the values at that time and the call stack to see what was called to create it.

Comment: I am working with some framework and there is lots of thing behind the scene. That is why I need something more than debugger. The problem is that I have a instance field which is instantiated twice with "new" operator and because of the framework way of working the old reference seems not to be deleted. I need to see the program heap to make sure what is going on.

Comment: @sznury, you haven't made it clear to me why you need more than a debugger. If your application/framework is not behaving they way it should, you have a bug. Can you clarify what you mean because an instance field can only be instantiated once (when the object is created) and you cannot have a reference to a field. I assume you are changing a field's value but you are still seeing the old value in the framework somehow.

Comment: it is too complicated to explain you in few words what is going on. Instance field A can be instantiated when the object is created and later if it hasn't _final_ modifier the value of A can be change using _new_ operator and that is the point.