# Viewing live heap in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

Is it possible to see the heap of a program in eclipse itself while it is executing? Is there a plugin for that?

Comment: what about "Show heap status" under Window -> Preferences -> General??

Comment: I meant to see heap contents... like a live heap dump?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932564/see-the-java-heap-content-in-run-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is an Eclipse plugin, but if what matters is getting the information and not necessarily through Eclipse then you can do that with [JVisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/), and there are several [plugins](http://visualvm.java.net/plugins.html) that provide all the details that you want.

One of its [features](http://visualvm.java.net/features.html) is that you can make a heap dump.

Documentation says:

> **Take and browse heap dumps.** When you need to browse contents of application memory or uncover a memory leak in your application,
>   you'll find the built-in HeapWalker tool really handy. It can read
>   files written in hprof format and is also able to browse heap dumps
>   created by the JVM on an OutOfMemoryException.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse does have a plugin called Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT). You can check it out here. I heard it is quite handy for heap analysis and fixing memory leaks in your program.

http://www.eclipse.org/mat/