# Visualization of the Java classes

Tags: java

I'm very new to programming and I have the following question.

I have a class:

```
class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
    }
}
```

I wish I could see the heaps, threads (internally & externally) that this program used etc.

Are there any tools for it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want, but VisualVM might be going in the right direction (it most likely comes with your JDK already).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a debugger, like integrated in Netbeans or Eclipse.

aslo this profiler might be helpful, but it is very advanced.

http://visualvm.java.net/ which is integrated in any recent jvm. But you cannot really see which Thread THIS particular code runs in.

Answer (score 1):

Look at following links:

[Java VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/heapdump.html)

[IBM HeapAnalyzer](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=4544bafe-c7a2-455f-9d43-eb866ea60091)

[How can I see what is in my heap in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145922/how-can-i-see-what-is-in-my-heap-in-java)

[Viewing live heap in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701337/viewing-live-heap-in-eclipse)